# How can I record system audio on iphone to a file?

Tags: iphone, audio, recording

Here's what I'm looking to do in xCode

1. Play an audio file on the iPhone
2. Allow the user to speak into the microphone (contributing to system audio)
3. Record the system audio (the combination of the audio file playing on the iphone and audio input from the mic)